# Python NameError: name 'name' is not defined functions

Tags: python

I'm making this program that prompts the user to enter their name and from there generate a username for them, like so:

```
Please enter your name: Stack Overflow
Your username is sove001
```

This is my code so far:

```
def get_name():
    name = str(input("Please enter your name: "))
    return name

def process_name(name):
    first_letter = name[0]
    first_space = name.find(" ")
    three_surname = name[first_space+1:first_space+4]
    nick_name = first_letter + three_surname
    final_name = nick_name.lower()
    return final_name

def zero_extend_number(number, length):
    number_str = str(number)
    padded_number = number_str.rjust(length, '0')
    return padded_number


def generate_username(number, number_length):
    get_name()
    process_name(name)
    zero_extend_number(number, length)
    completed_name = final_name + padded_number
    print("Your username is: {}".format(completed_name))

generate_username(1,4)
```

Running this gives the following ouput:

```
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

I'm not really sure what is wrong with my code, have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the return value of `get_name()`

```
def generate_username(number, number_length):
    name = get_name()
```

Answer (score 0):

From every function you are returning value so output that it returns needs to be collected in some variable. I have modified code for generate_username() as below, try it:

```
def generate_username(number, number_length):
    name = get_name()
    final_name = process_name(name)
    padded_number = zero_extend_number(number, number_length)
    completed_name = final_name + padded_number
    print("Your username is: {}".format(completed_name))
```